# how to prevent all MDI child from being maximized, if one of the MDI child is maximized

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, mdichild

I have a MDI form with multiple child, when i maximize a MDI child it will automatically Maximize all the child.
I do not want to use Set Maximum size or Set Minimum Size property. Is there any way to prevent this behaviour of mdi children ?

Comment: You are swimming upstream.  That is what MDI Children are supposed to do.  Anything you do in opposition to that will be brute force.

Answer (score 2):

add an event handler for each child form on Activate Event. And in the method set the window state as normal.

```
Private Sub Form1_Activated(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Activated
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
End Sub
```

Comment: Above Code will make ALL THE OPENED MDI CHILD to be in State NORMAL. How to make Only One Child to be Normal State ??

Comment: you can loop through all the opened MDI child forms using a `for each` loop from MDI parent form. When you get your required form, set its state to normal.